# Error android...CoordinadorLayout - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

me gustaría aprende a desarrollar aplicaciones moviles con android studio pero me sale un error en el emuador ADK, sabrían, que problema es, y como solucionarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que al instalar el Android Studio, que fué todo bien, me antes no me ejecutaba el emulador, pero le hice una cosa... no sé el qué... y se me puso, el emulador pero me sale la pantalla en gris con 'android...CoordinatorLayout', he visto que en la parte derecha arriba en el apartado de 'text', hay una pequeña exclamacion que me informa de que hay el siguiente error:
[image]

Parece decir, que falló al encontrar el estilo coordinatorLayoutStyle', eso que quiere decir?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la respuesta, el error esta en build.gradle (Module: app):
en el apartado de dependencies:

Le tenia que poner:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

A veces según tu PC te saldrá así:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

o
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'

Si te sale tanto una forma como la otra tienes que poner esto si o si:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

Fuente: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nG7VqLkKCfw

Answer (score 0):

Es un error muy común con la version 28 del `SDK`.
Una solución es ir a el `gradle` y disminuir la version del Sdk a 27:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27
```

Y también cambiar las `implemantation` a la versión 27:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Tendrás que bajar el SDK 27, así:

```
 File-Settings-Appearance & Behavior-System Settings-Android SDK-SDK Platforms- Android 8.1 (Oreo) API Level 27
```

Comment: Hola, estoy desde donde me bajo el SDK 27? El código que me ha puesto lo debo poner en el sitio?

Answer (score 0):

Inserta esta línea abajo, en el tema de la aplicación.

`<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
</style>`

Comment: Hola, ¿En que archivo tengo que insertarlo, en el content_main.xml?

Comment: Debes insertarlo en Styles.xml

Comment: Ok, pero cuando lo puse me da dos errores: En el AppTheme.NoActionBar ya que me dice que no hay ninguna carpeta, y en el @style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout, que me señala en rojo

Comment: Prueba a añadir estas dos dependencias en tu build.gradle(app) : 
dependencies { 
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2' 
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2' 
}